# "Cannot resolve symbol" in XML files in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Suddenly I am getting the red stylings of IDEA letting me know that it cannot resolve my JSP paths in my struts-config.xml file. E.g., I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'Definition /WEB-INF/pages/healthCheck.jsp'" when I mouseover the path in the following forward:

```
<action path="/monitor/lb-healthcheck"
        type="com.rc.mexp.action.HealthCheck"
        scope="request">
    <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/pages/healthCheck.jsp"/>
</action>
```

In my view IDEA is displaying "/WEB-INF/pages/healthCheck.jsp" in red. The code builds fine, as normal, but IDEA suddenly doesn't know how to resolve it. Can't find anything useful in a Google search. To reiterate, this was all fine but is now fekachteh. I don't think I did anything that could have caused this. I tried restarting IDEA, invalidating caches, and re-specifying the path to JVM, but none of these things fixed it. I am running 9.0.4 (I know, I know) on Snow Leopard.

So the code works fine, but it's inconvenient IDEA not knowing how to get to my JSPs. I would greatly appreciate any help fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to reset caches by deleting the system directory? See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Comment: No dice. Still can't resolve any jsp locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - forgot I had this question open. I ended up upgrading to v11 - our IT group got us licenses - and that fixed it. It's not really a direct answer, but it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to change location of web resources in Idea. Press ctrl+shift+alt+S -> modules -> Web and change your "Web resource directory" to folder, where your WEB-INF is in.